# Why is this dictionary comprehension for list of dictionaries not returning values?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I am iterating over a list of dictionaries in a list formatted as follows (each dictionary relates to one item of clothing, I have only listed the first:

```
new_products = [{'{"uniq_id": "1234", "sku": "abcdefgh", "name": "Levis skinny jeans", '
                 '"list_price": "75.00", "sale_price": "55.00", "category": "womens"}'}]
```

```py
def find_product(dictionary, uniqid):
    if 'uniq_id' in dictionary:
        if ['uniq_id'] == uniqid:
            return(keys, values in dictionary)

print(find_product(new_products, '1234'))
```

This is returning

```
None
```

The reason for the `if` statement in there is that not every product has a value for `uniq_id` so I was getting a key error on an earlier version of my code.

Comment: The problem is the dictionary with `"uniq_id"` in it is a **string representation** of a dictionary in the `new_products` list not an actual dictionary object—so it's never seen by your `if`.

Comment: But print(type(reviewers_dicts[1])) returns dict.

Comment: Don't know what `reviewers_dicts` is. From what's shown in your question: `type(new_products[0])` → `<class 'set'>`, and the string representation of the dictionary is the member of that `set` which is the first (and only) element of the `new_products` list. Your data structure is messed-up.

Answer (score 0):

Your dictionary definition is quite unclear.

Assuming that you have given a list of dictionaries of size 1, it should be something like this:

```
new_products = [{"uniq_id": "1234", "sku": "abcdefgh", "name": "Levis skinny jeans", "list_price": "75.00", "sale_price": "55.00", "category": "womens"}]

def find_product(list_of_dicts, uniqid):
    for dictionary in list_of_dicts:
        if 'uniq_id' in dictionary:
            if dictionary['uniq_id'] == uniqid:
                return dictionary

print(find_product(new_products, '1234'))
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not able to share my actual data - but type is coming back as dictionary for all elements of the list. However, @kkgarg code is also giving me an output of None so I accept that it is perhaps a data structure issue.

Comment: We need at least one entry of the dataset to work with, numbers could be cooked up but the type should be the same. Otherwise we can hardly do anything about the question. I inferred the type from your question "list of dictionaries". BTW, the above sample returns the dict `{'uniq_id': '1234', 'sku': 'abcdefgh', 'name': 'Levis skinny jeans', 'list_price': '75.00', 'sale_price': '55.00', 'category': 'womens'}` not `None`

Comment: Sure. Here is the first dictionary and beginning of second

Comment: [{'{"uniq_id": "b6c0b6bea69c722939585baeac73c13d", "sku": "pp5006380337", "name_title": "Alfred Dunner\\u00ae Essential Pull On Capri Pant", "description": "You\'ll return to our Alfred Dunner pull-on capris again and again when you want an updated, casual look and all the comfort you love. \\u00a0 elastic waistband approx. 19-21\\" inseam slash pockets polyester washable imported \\u00a0 \\u00a0 \\u00a0", "list_price": "41.09", "sale_price": "24.16", "category": "alfred dunner", "category_tree": "jcpenney|women|alfred dunner", "average_product_rating": 2.625]}\n': '{"uniq_id": "93e527

Comment: Not sure why you have `:` before your second entry! Also how does the first brace `{` end - after all the entries? Please add these details in your question for clarity.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient @kkgarg. The end of the list, with the last value is "90c46b841e2eeece992c57071387899c"]}\n']).    I have converted from JSON to this list of dictionaries and so I am wondering now if the data structure is wrong, although I am getting type list for the list of dictionaries and type dict for the first item in that list

Answer (score 0):

You are using something like this:

```
new_products = [{'{ "some" : "stuff" }'}]
```

This is a list (the outer `[]`) containing a set (the `{}`)

```
{'{ "some" : "stuff" }'}
```

Note `{1}` is a set containing the number 1. Though it uses the curly braces it isn't a dictionary.

Your set contains a string:

```
'{ "some" : "stuff" }'
```

If I ask if 'some' is in this, I get `True` back, but if I ask for this string's keys there are no keys.

Make your `new_products` a list containing a dictionary (not a set), and don't put the payload in a string:

```
new_products = [{"uniq_id": "1234", 
                 "sku": "abcdefgh",
                 "name": "Levis skinny jeans",
                 "list_price": "75.00",
                 "sale_price": "55.00",
                 "category": "womens"}]
```

Then loop over the dictionaries in the list in your function:

```
def find_product(dictionary_list, uniqid):
    for d in dictionary_list:
        if 'uniq_id' in d:
            if d['uniq_id'] == uniqid:
                 return d.keys(), d.values()
    return "not found" # or something better



>>> find_product(new_products, '1234')
(dict_keys(['uniq_id', 'sku', 'name', 'list_price', 'sale_price', 'category']), dict_values(['1234', 'abcdefgh', 'Levis skinny jeans', '75.00', '55.00', 'womens']))
>>> find_product(new_products, '12345')
'not found'
```